# Is it bad to create a public static object

Tags: java, object

Is it bad to declare an object like this

```
     public static GUI g = new GUI();
```

or should I avoid creating a public object when I want multiple methods to be able to use the same object?

Comment: public, only if `public static final` (constant)

Comment: It's perfectly legit, and often done.  Sometimes it's done in appropriate circumstances and sometimes not.  It's up to you to judge it it's appropriate.  (Is there any reason why you felt it would not be appropriate?)

Comment: Be more specific in your requirements. Multiple methods is not the same as multiple threads. A static like this is fine for a single threaded application, but do follow the recommended approach for implementing the singleton pattern in your language. My personal taste is to use a static method named Instance() to retrieve the object, and make the instance variable private.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is generally bad to expose an object as a public static variable, because everybody has a write access to it. Making the variable `final` make it slightly better, but the best solution would be to make your variable `private`, and provide a static getter.

Comment: Making it private and providing a static getter adds nothing.

Comment: Yep.  Pass it explicitly to every class that needs it; avoid making it static in the first place.

Comment: @HotLicks That is true only if you add a trivial getter. But you re not limited to trivial getters: you could easily add deferred initialization, retiring an instance at runtime, and so on.

Comment: @Mayankswami -- Only if you understand why you're using it.

Comment: @HotLicks That is an excellent point! It is applicable not only to getters, but also to many other things well outside the scope of programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Static state is generally considered untestable, and bad.  Every static object is an implicit input to everything you're trying to test, and tests are all about controlling the inputs and experimenting how your methods behave in response to precise parameters.

Instead, you should pass an explicit reference to the GUI object to every class that needs it.  There are a number of ways to simplify the bookkeeping involved; typically involving *dependency injection*.

Answer (score 1):

The concept has come to be referred to as the "singleton" model.  Not as popular in Java as in some other languages such as Objective-C.  It's a concept that everyone criticizes but everyone uses, though usually disguised one way or another.

The big problem with global data in general is that too often too much data that doesn't/shouldn't need to be global is made global, because that's simpler than figuring out how to partition your data appropriately and manage its addressability.  This causes the intellectual complexity of your application to grow exponentially, and it can very quickly get out of control.

So there's nothing wrong with using a global static (whether `final` or not) in a few appropriate cases.  The danger is that you fall into the habit of using it in *every* case, or at least so many that you no longer can understand your application.  This goes double (or maybe quadruple) in a multi-developer environment.

Comment: Class variables aren't necessarily singletons.  Singletons must ensure that only one copy of the class can be instantiated.  This ain't that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern to do what you are trying to achieve is [Singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html)

Comment: public non static is a singleton?

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth -- public static.

Comment: at least it should be encapsulated isn't it? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: No, I'm saying the right way to do it is a singleton. I'll edit to make that clearer.

Comment: I don't believe it's actually a singleton if you can create other copies of it.  For it to be a singleton, you have to a) make the constructor private, b) provide a static creation method that creates the object and in the future returns the same copy.

Comment: "when I want multiple methods to be able to use the same object?" -> multiple functions want access to the same object -> make a Singleton.